# How to Extend and add an argument to a block with no name

Tags: magento2

I have a block

`<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml">`

That comes from

`module-sales\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml`

This block does not have a name and I can't figure out how to reference it. My objective is to display a new data-field I added to order item tables called item-comment.

In my modules `\Company\ModuleName\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml` I have

```
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_items">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="item-comment" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Comment</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments> 

        <referenceBlock name="default">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="item-comment" xsi:type="string" translate="true">col-item-comment</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

I was able to successfully extend the `order_items` block but not the renderer block

Answer (score 0):

use "default_order_items_renderer" instead "default" and it is working

```
<referenceContainer name="left">        
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">                
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">                           
                    <item name="promised_date" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Promised Date</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
            <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">                     
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">                                
                        <item name="promised_date" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-promised-date</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>                  
        </referenceBlock>          
    </referenceContainer>
```